# Finding center of geometry of object?

Tags: geometry, 3d, algorithm, centroids

Given a set of 2D or 3D points:

**How to find the center of geometry of an object?**

According to the following figure, the center of geometry differs from the center of mass if it is calculated in the simplest form i.e., homogenous density of mass. The problem appears, indeed, in the computation of those.
Commonly, one approach is to average **X** coordinates and **Y** coordinates separately i.e., find an average position to the given points (here in 2D). This may be used as centroid for the set of points representing an object.
As shown, *due to the extra vertex along the bottom edge,* for a simple rectangle the resulting centroid is **(0.5,0.4)** while the correct answer is **(0.5,0.5)**.
Note that the example given is too simple. The problem of interest however is for complex shapes in 2D and objects in 3D for which only coordinates of vertices are available.
BTW, an efficient computational way is of interest.

Just to mention that I have checked some web links such as Wikipedia's however my current problem is that there are group of 2D and 3D points wish to find a point as representative for those. Thus centroid became of interest. The points are given without any topological information. You may consider them as point cloud. The demonstration here provided to make it clear that the commonly known averaging of coordinates (see for example [this Stack Overflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77936/whats-the-best-way-to-calculate-a-3d-or-n-d-centroid)) may be incorrect as shown in the example.

[image]

Here are some implementations for comparison:

- **aa**    = accepted answer below
- chull = convex-hull of points i.e., the golden polygon
- cent  = centroid proposed in Wikipedia and discussed in **aa** as the polygon centroid
- centl = centroid of polyline as explained in **aa**

Visually, `centl` looks better representative for the geometry given compared to `cent`. Two others look promising here but usually they are too biased if the dispersion of the points were inhomogeneous as it is a usual case.
And also consider that although convex-hull makes problem reasonably simpler however it may generate too long and too short edges without any symmetrical positioning in the space, that is, awareness is necessary if you do simple averaging (i.e., without weighting) for both cases: entire points (green) or convex-hull polygon vertices (blue).

[image]

One application could be found in [Finding minimum-area-rectangle for given points?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22895/how-to-find-the-minimum-area-rectangle-for-given-points/22904#22904).

Comment: Will this work?

[Finding the centroid of a polygon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792443/finding-the-centroid-of-a-polygon) (StackOverflow)

Comment: I am not sure what your Question is. Center of Geometry or (usually the centroid) can be different from barycenter (center of mass). This is a well known fact. Also there are various ways to calculate the center of a geometry. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_center , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encyclopedia_of_Triangle_Centers & http://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html.

Comment: I added an update for clarification.

Comment: @blah238 That is what I just coded similar (in Python) using the formula given in Wikipedia page for Polygon. Not sure it is correct also for my problem explained above. Also reminder that it is only for 2D polygons.

Comment: Re the update: when there is no topology, a point cloud is just a point cloud. Your figure of a polygonal square does not apply (and your 'centroid' of (0.5,0.4) does not appear to arise from any standard formula, by the way: symmetry argues strongly for *any* central point of the square to coincide with (0.5,0.5), no matter how it is defined).  For some ideas about finding representative or central locations for point clouds in two and more dimensions, please see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1927.

Comment: I don't understand how the (0.5, 0.4) "center of mass" was obtained either, unless the vertices are weighted inequally and that fact was not noted.

Comment: @blah238 It is a simple averaging of coordinates for all five points.

Comment: @whuber The method that I use now is to find a convex-hull of the points as in the given example. Then applying Centroid for the produced polygon as in Wikipedia. I am thinking about similar in 3D. As mentioned my interest is a (geometrical) center = centroid.

Comment: Developer, (1) Your proposed convex hull approach is the basis for many of those discussed in the link I posted earlier.  That shows it is both legitimate and can be exploited further in several ways if you wish.  Note, though, that it is not a barycenter of the points.  (2) I believe the 0.4 coordinate for your center of mass may be a numerical mistake: the average of the y-coordinates is (1+1+0+0)/4 = 1/2 = 0.5.  In any rectangle the three barycenters described in my reply always coincide and lie on the intersection of the rectangle's symmetry axes (its obvious visual center).

Comment: @Developer, I see your point now, your 5th point on the bottom of the "rectangle" (actually a polygon) makes a simple averaging of vertex coordinates yield a different barycenter than that of a polygon as whuber's answer explains.

Comment: Aha!  I completely missed that fifth vertex, even though I had been looking for some such thing.  To help future readers, I have made a slight edit in the question to point this out.  This really does get to the heart of the matter, too: inserting or deleting vertices along edges will change how a poly{line,gon} is *represented*, but it should not change the computation of its innate geometric properties.  That is why the barycenter of the vertices can have an almost arbitrary relationship to the barycenters of a polygon or its boundary.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**Every polygon has, at a minimum, four distinct "centers":**

- The barycenter of its vertices.
- The barycenter of its edges.
- Its barycenter as a polygon.
- A GIS-specific "center" useful for labeling (usually calculated with undocumented proprietary methods).

(They may accidentally coincide in special cases, but for "generic" polygons they are distinct points.)

A "barycenter" in general is a "center of mass."  The three types differ on where the mass is presumed located: it either is entirely on the vertices, spread uniformly on the edges, or spread uniformly throughout the polygon itself.

Simple methods exist to compute all three barycenters.  One approach relies on the basic fact that *the barycenter of the disjoint union of two masses is the total-mass-weighted average of the barycenters.*  From this we easily obtain the following:

1. The barycenter of two (equally weighted) vertices is their average.  This is obtained by averaging their coordinates separately.  Geometrically, it is the midpoint of the line segment joining the two vertices.
2. Inductively, **the barycenter of *n* (equally weighted) vertices** is obtained by averaging their coordinates separately.
3. **The barycenter of a line segment** is its midpoint.  (This is clear by symmetry.)
4. **The barycenter of a polyline** is obtained by finding the midpoints of each line segment and then forming their weighted average using the segment lengths as weights.

   For example, consider the "L" shape delineated by the points (0,0), (6,0), (6,12).  There are two segments: one of length 6 with midpoint at ( (0+0)/2, (0+6)/2 ) = (3,0) and another of length 12 with midpoint at ( (6+6)/2, (0+12)/2 ) = (6,6).  Their length-weighted average coordinates are therefore (x,y) with

   ```
   x = (6*3 + 12*6) / (6+12) = 5,  y = (6*0 + 12*6) / (6+12) = 4.
   ```

   This differs from the barycenter of the three vertices, which is ( (0+6+6)/3, (0+0+12)/3 ) = (4,4).

   (*Edit* As another example, consider the figure in the question, which although square in shape, is represented as a *pentagon* determined by the sequence of points (0,0), (1/2,0), (1,0), (1,1), (0,1).  The five sides have lengths 1/2, 1/2, 1, 1, 1 and midpoints (1/4,0), (3/4,0), (1,1/2), (1/2,1), and (0,1/2), respectively.  Their weighted average therefore equals

   ```
   [(1/2)*(1/4, 0) + (1/2)*(3/4, 0) + (1)*(1, 1/2) + (1)*(1/2, 1) + (1)*(0, 1/2)] / (1/2+1/2+1+1+1)
   = (2/4, 2/4) = (0.5, 0.5)
   ```

   as one would hope, even though the barycenter of the vertices alone (computed as in #2 above) is (0.5, 0.4).)
5. **The barycenter of a polygon** can be obtained by triangulation to decompose it into triangles.  The barycenter of a triangle-qua-polygon coincides with the barycenter of its vertices.  The area-weighted average of these barycenters is the polygon's barycenter.  Triangle areas are readily computed in terms of their vertex coordinates (e.g., in terms of the [wedge product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Areas_in_the_plane) of two of the sides).  For an illustration of such area calculations, including how to exploit signed (positive or negative) areas, see the section on "Area" at my (old) [course notes page](http://www.courses.psu.edu/in_sc/in_sc597b_wah5/Notes/01july.htm).

   (*Edit* Consider the polygon depicted in the question for example.  We could triangulate it with triangles ((0,0), (1/2,0), (0,1)) on the left, ((0,1), (1/2,0), (1,1)) in the middle, and ((1,1), (1,0), (1/2,0)) on the right.  Their areas are 1/4, 1/2, 1/4 respectively and their barycenters--obtained by averaging their vertices--are (1/6,1/3), (1/2,2/3), and (5/6,1/3), respectively.  The area-weighted average of these barycenters equals

   ```
   [(1/4)*(1/6,1/3) + (1/2)*(1/2,2/3) + (1/4)*(5/6,1/3)] / (1/4 + 1/2 + 1/4)
   = (12/24, 6/12)
   = (0.5, 0.5)
   ```

   as it should, despite the presence of that fifth vertex along the bottom edge.)

It is evident that **each of these methods is efficient**: it requires just a single pass over the "spaghetti" representation of the polygon, using (fairly little) constant time at each step.  Note that in all cases except the first (of pure vertices), *more* information than just a list of vertex coordinates is needed: you need to know the topology of the figure as well.  In the "L" example, we needed to know that (0,0) was connected to (6,0) and not to (6,12), for instance.

**These are all Euclidean concepts.**  They can be extended to the sphere (or ellipsoid) in several ways.  A straightforward one views the features as a simplicial complex in three (Euclidean) dimensions, computes the appropriate barycenter, and then projects it outward from the center of the ellipsoid back to the surface.  This requires no new concepts or formulas; you only have to work with a third (z) coordinate in addition to the first two coordinates.  (Areas are *still* found using lengths of wedge products.)

**Another generalization** recognizes that the Euclidean metric--the square root of a sum of squares, according to Pythagoras--can be changed to other [Lp metrics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#The_p-norm_in_finite_dimensions) for p >= 1: you take the pth root of the sum of pth powers.  Finding appropriate "barycenters" is no longer so simple, because the beautiful additive properties exploited above (barycenters are weighted averages of barycenters of simpler parts of a figure) no longer hold in general.  Often, iterative approximate numerical solutions have to be obtained.  They might not even be unique.

**Additional centers can be defined** for various purposes.  Triangles have many different centers that can generalize (somewhat) to polygons: the center of the circumcircle, the center of (some) maximal incircle, the center of a minimum-area bounding ellipse, and others.  Any set can be enclosed in various "hulls," such as the convex hull, and the centers of those hulls obtained.

Note that many of these "centers" are not necessarily located within the interior of a polygon.  (Any reasonable center of a *convex* polygon will lie within its interior, though.)

This variety of approaches and solutions indicates one should be wary of a generic term like "center of geometry" or merely "center": it could be just about anything.

Comment: To community: Such a good answer like this from 'whuber' can be expected only for a good question, as my familiarity with his preference, thus, would you everybody mind to up-vote the question too if you found it interesting ;)

Comment: I found it useful in some sence, wish to give sometime to other contirbuters as motivation for answering. I mark this however an accepatable constructive answer so far.

Comment: Can you explain why areas are *still* found using wedge products on a sphere? Wouldn't the spherical triangle area be more appropriate? The closest reference (aside from this excellent answer!) that I've found is: http://www.jennessent.com/downloads/Graphics_Shapes_Online.pdf - which uses areas of spherical triangles.

Comment: @Jason I am intrigued: how do you propose using spherical triangle areas to compute *barycenters* of spherical features?

Comment: @whuber The spherical polygon is decomposed into spherical triangles, and the barycenter of each triangle is computed by averaging the Cartesian coordinates of its vertices. I'm proposing that the polygon barycenter is the weighted average of these triangles, where the weight is the *spherical* triangle area, not the planar area as you suggested in your answer (assuming I understand the wedge product correctly).

Comment: There are some problems with this proposal, Jason. Most stem from the fact that you will get different answers depending on how you triangulate. Also, it seems to be inconsistent: if you are forming a weighted average of the (spherical) centers of the triangles, you are performing a *Euclidean* calculation, not a spherical one: at best we could say that this procedure is an approximation to something. But to what? Generally, it helps to specify what *properties* your central point should have and then derive a means to compute it based on those properties. What properties do you have in mind?

Comment: @whuber Additionally, note that my reference claims it is possible to decompose into triangles based on a reference point external to the polygon, such that negative spherical triangle areas provide a negative weighting for those centroids. However, I'm running into difficulties in my implementation with some trivial test cases, hence my search for other references. I'm not 100% sure this negative weighting will work properly, hence my search for other references. :)

Comment: @whuber Aha, thanks. If different triangulations can produce different results, then that could explain my implementation issues.

Comment: @whuber This is for a general geographic library, so I want it to be as "useful" as possible, i.e. something reasonably standard compared with other libraries would be fine. One test case that we have is rotating a globe so that it "centres" on a given feature, and we're using the feature centroid for this. The other is of course labelling, although I'm aware that there are perhaps more appropriate ways to find a label position.

Comment: @whuber Also, it's not immediately obvious to me why decomposing into spherical triangles and weighting their centroids by their (spherical) areas wouldn't work correctly, perhaps you can give a hint?

Comment: @whuber I've already successfully implemented centroids for points (arithmetic mean of Cartesian vectors) and lines (weighted mean of midpoints using distance between points as weight). So something analogous would be preferable for polygons.

Comment: You pose some interesting questions here, @Jason, but comment threads are not the place for them: they are best asked as new questions.  See our [faq] for guidance if you're not familiar with how this site works.