# Polygon symmetry detection

Tags: python, qgis, vector

I was wondering if there was any way to create main axis (axis of symmetry) lines for polygons.
I have polygons that represents buildings.
I will want to find main axes (axis of symmetry) for those buildings and axis direction respect to a cardinal point.
Best regards
Stefano

Comment: Are all building polygons guaranteed to be rectangles?  If so, are you assured that they are represented by exactly four vertices (and not more, as shown at http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/22739)?

Comment: building polygons are often represented by more than 4 vertices (eg worship places)