# How to measure similarity of approximately congruent polylines

Tags: r, line, similarity

My initial question was posted [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130848/how-to-measure-similarity-of-spatiallines-objects/130871?noredirect=1#comment187538_130871). The answer of [whuber](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/664/whuber) provides a nice solution for the case when polylines are congruent.

However, the problem is that my polylines are *approximately congruent* (an example of the small difference of polylines is marked in black):

[image]

The objective is to measure the similarity between two polylines, assuming that small deviations (around 5%) are allowed and must be ignored. So, the similarity between above provided polylines must be close to 100%.

The question is how to measure similarity between such polylines using R? My approach is explained [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130848/how-to-measure-similarity-of-spatiallines-objects/130871?noredirect=1#comment187538_130871), however it is very computationally expensive, and the solution of [whuber](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/664/whuber) assumes that polylines are congruent, not *approximately congruent*.

Comment: A related thread has just been started on [stats.SE] at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134202.  (It's not yet clear where it will go, but you might want to monitor it.)